# mysql select all calculate difference bewteen multiple rows to on result from pivot

Tags: mysql, datetime, pivot, rows, group-concat

I have an pivot table from an root table here on SQL Fiddle, this link: [pivot operation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e27a4/1)

Here I try to calculate the difference between "Arbeitszeit", "Arbeitsende" and between "Projektzeit" and "Projektende".

The problem is, if there is more than one value, the calculation does not work, like this:

> 19.06.2013 07:27:27,19.06.2013 09:08:58

I need the data either seperated or in best case, merged to see just the result of the differnces.

There is no possibility to get the root data in any other way because this is generated by an interface-

Comment: If you have multiple values, which one do you want to calculate the difference between?  Or do you want the total difference between each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the data is coming in the concatenated form -- not that you are created it.  You can unconcatenate it using `substring_index()` and `reverse()`, along with a table that generates numbers.

The following query undoes the concatenate, then groups the results back together:

```
select t.*,
  sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS ARBEITSZEIT,
  sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Projektbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE(Projektbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS Projektzeit
FROM (select DriverName,
             (case when n.n = 1 then substring_index(arbeitsbeginn, ',', 1)
                   else reverse(substring_index(REVERSE(substring_index(arbeitsbeginn, ',', 2)), ',', 1))
              end) as arbeitsbeginn,
             (case when n.n = 1 then substring_index(arbeitsende, ',', 1)
                   else reverse(substring_index(REVERSE(substring_index(arbeitsende, ',', 2)), ',', 1))
              end) as arbeitsende,
             (case when n.n = 1 then substring_index(Projektbeginn, ',', 1)
                   else reverse(substring_index(REVERSE(substring_index(Projektbeginn, ',', 2)), ',', 1))
              end) as Projektbeginn,
             (case when n.n = 1 then substring_index(Projektbeginn, ',', 1)
                   else reverse(substring_index(REVERSE(substring_index(ProjektEnde, ',', 2)), ',', 1))
              end) as ProjektEnde
      from (SELECT DRIVERNAME, 
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsbeginn', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsbeginn', 
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsende', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsende', 
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektbeginn',
                   GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PE', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektende'
            FROM geoImportRoot
            GROUP BY DRIVERNAME
           ) A cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
    ) t
group by DriverName
```